# How to make a 2v2 rotation with 5 people

Tags: strategy, real

I'm running a volleyball club at school and we currently have 5 active members. Is there a way of having everybody play in a duo with everybody else and have one person sit out each game practising? I posted this here because this is more a maths problem than a volleyball one.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE, @JamesMann ! Any relation to [Leslie](http://wallpapersdsc.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Leslie-Mann-High-Definition-Wallpapers.jpg)? ;)

Answer (score 5):

The answer is:

> Sure, of course.

Have a look at the following diagram:

> [image: Pairing]

If you:

> Let each dot be a player. Then rotate that diagram 5 times: the lone circled person will be each person exactly once, each pair of adjacent people will be the green (upper) pair exactly once, and each pair of non-adjacent people will be the red (lower) pair exactly once.

Here is one possible roster:

> ```
> 2-5 vs 3-4 (1 alone)
> 3-1 vs 4-5 (2 alone)
> 4-2 vs 5-1 (3 alone)
> 5-3 vs 1-2 (4 alone)
> 1-4 vs 2-3 (5 alone)
> ```